# UIViewController failing to navigate to another page in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, viewcontroller

I have previously written this function and it was working fine. I started working on the project again after a week's break and the same code is not working. Am I missing something here? Basically if a button is pushed, `checkCredentials` will run. Everything in the "else" section is working completely fine, but the `if user != nil` section isn't working:

```
func checkCredentials (){
  PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameLoginTxt.text!, password: passwordLoginTxt.text!){
    (user:PFUser?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if user != nil{


        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchViewController") as UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion:nil)
        NSLog("it was successfull dude")

    }else{

        let title = "Warning!"
        let message = "You have entered the wrong username or password.\n Please try again!"
        let okButton = "Ok"
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle:  UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: okButton, style:  UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler:  nil)
        alert.addAction(okayButton)

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a value in `error`? Sounds like something might be going wrong with the Parse request

Comment: Can you clarify if you see the NSLog message? If not, then either user == nil and your code is not executed or the whole completion handler is not executed (might be due to an error in response). In fact, the later would explain why it was working one week ago and doesn't work now :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you...

```
   func login(){
      let user = PFUser()
      user.username = userNameText.text
      user.password = passwordText.text

  PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userNameText.text!, password: passwordText.text!, block: {
        (user: PFUser?, Error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if Error == nil {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let AfterLoginVC: UIViewController = Storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AfterLoginVC") as! UINavigationController
                self.presentViewController(AfterLoginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        } else {
    let title = "Warning!"
    let message = "You have entered the wrong username or password.\n Please try again!"
    let okButton = "Ok"
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle:  UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: okButton, style:  UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler:  nil)
    alert.addAction(okayButton)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
 }
```

Also be sure that over the last week you didn't accidentally change your Parse client key (I've done that before) which will cause it to not show any error but simply to not work.